# OpenGL+ QT 5.0.1 + VS2010: error C2371: 'GLdouble' : redefinition; different basic types

Tags: qt, opengl, glut

I have installed QT5.0.1 and I am trying to use GLUT.
I have the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(55): error C2371: 'GLdouble' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\include\QtGui/qopengl.h(71) : see declaration of 'GLdouble'

I cant understand what can be wrong and what to do.

Comment: GLUT development stopped in 1998. It's time to start learning modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

> I have installed **QT5.0.1** and I am trying to use **GLUT**

Pick *one* and *only one* framework.

Trying to use Qt *and* GLUT at the same time will only result in problems because they both want to own the event loop.